# LinkedList - Get current and previous when traversing

Tags: java, list, iteration

I have a LinkedList, and need to know the current, previous, and next item when iterating thru it. I guess there is no way to do this with the "for each" notation, so I turned to list iterators. They have turned out to be rather confusing.

Anyways, I have an implementation of what seems to keep track of current, previous, and next.

```
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    list.add("p");
    list.add("r");
    list.add("r");
    list.add("q");
    list.add("p");
    list.add("p");
    list.add("r");

    String prev = "";
    String next = "";
    String curr = "";
    Boolean firstRun = true;

    ListIterator<String> li = list.listIterator();

    while (li.hasNext()) {
        curr = li.next();

        if (firstRun) {
            prev = "-";
            firstRun = false;
        } else if (li.hasPrevious()) {
            prev = li.previous();
            li.next();
            if (li.hasNext())
                curr = li.next();
        } else
            prev = "-";

        if (li.hasNext()) {
            next = li.next();
            li.previous();
            if (li.hasPrevious())
                curr = li.previous();
        } else
            next = "-";

        System.out.println(curr + prev + next);
    }
```

This outputs

```
p-r
rpr
rrq
qrp
pqp
ppr
rp-
```

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this. The code is cluttered, and non intuitive, at least how I interpret it.

Edit: I have abstracted the real actual I am trying to solve. Instead of Strings, I have a list of objects such as:

```
public foo(String name, String data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data
}
```

If foo.name is "alone", i.e. the next and prev items are different, I want to keep track of foo.data

If foo.name is repeated, then I want to keep track of the first and last instance of foo.data, relative to the items around it.

i.e.

```
list.add(new foo("ben", "clock");
list.add(new foo("Joe", "paper");
list.add(new foo("Joe", "pen");
list.add(new foo("Joe", "pencil");
list.add(new foo("greg", "couch");
list.add(new foo("sam", "desk");
list.add(new foo("sam", "book");
list.add(new foo("Joe", "earbuds");
list.add(new foo("Joe", "sail");
list.add(new foo("Joe", "watch");
```

Going thru this list, we are interested in:

```
clock, paper, pencil, couch, desk, book, earbuds, watch
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might help you get an answer if you tell us _why_ you need to keep track of the previous, current, and next positions.  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I have edited the post, please let me know if you would like more clarity

Comment: then why use iterator? just use loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to make it overly complex. You know the previous object, because you just went past it. Actually, the "current" object is the one before "next" too, so if you just remember the last 3 items during iteration, you have "prev", "curr", and "next" right there.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("p", "r", "r", "q", "p", "p", "r"));

String prev = null;
String curr = null;
String next = "-";
for (String value : list) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
    next = value;
    if (prev != null)
        System.out.println(curr + prev + next);
}
prev = curr;
curr = next;
next = "-";
System.out.println(curr + prev + next);
```

*Output*

```
p-r
rpr
rrq
qrp
pqp
ppr
rp-
```

Or, if you don't like the extra step after the loop:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("p", "r", "r", "q", "p", "p", "r"));

String prev = null, curr = "-", next = null;
for (Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); prev == null || ! "-".equals(next); prev = curr, curr = next) {
    next = (iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : "-");
    if (prev != null)
        System.out.println(curr + prev + next);
}
```

Same output.

---

As for your *real* logic...

> If `foo.name` is "alone", i.e. the next and prev items are different, I want to keep track of `foo.data`
>
> If `foo.name` is repeated, then I want to keep track of the first and last instance of `foo.data`, relative to the items around it.

This really means that you want to keep track of a *streak*, i.e. a sequence of values with the same `name`, keeping track of first and last item, and the streak length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Foo> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Foo("ben", "clock"),
            new Foo("Joe", "paper"),
            new Foo("Joe", "pen"),
            new Foo("Joe", "pencil"),
            new Foo("greg", "couch"),
            new Foo("sam", "desk"),
            new Foo("sam", "book"),
            new Foo("Joe", "earbuds"),
            new Foo("Joe", "sail"),
            new Foo("Joe", "watch")
    ));
    
    String streakName = null;
    int streakLength = 0;
    String firstData = null;
    String lastData = null;
    for (Foo foo : list) {
        if (! foo.getName().equals(streakName)) {
            if (streakLength != 0)
                processStreak(streakName, streakLength, firstData, lastData);
            streakName = foo.getName();
            streakLength = 0;
            firstData = foo.getData();
        }
        streakLength++;
        lastData = foo.getData();
    }
    if (streakLength != 0)
        processStreak(streakName, streakLength, firstData, lastData);
}
private static void processStreak(String name, int length, String firstData, String lastData) {
    if (length == 1)
        System.out.println("Alone: name=" + name + ", data=" + firstData);
    else
        System.out.println("Repeated: name=" + name + ", first=" + firstData + ", last=" + lastData);
}
```

*Output*

```
Alone: name=ben, data=clock
Repeated: name=Joe, first=paper, last=pencil
Alone: name=greg, data=couch
Repeated: name=sam, first=desk, last=book
Repeated: name=Joe, first=earbuds, last=watch
```